# Image of Sylow $p$-subgroup is Sylow $p$-subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, group-homomorphism

> If $f:G\to H$ is an epimorphism between finite groups and $K\subset G$ a Sylow p-group then I want to show that $f(K)\subset H$ is also a Sylow p-group.

So we want to show that $|f(K)|=p^m$ where $m$ is the biggest power such that $|H|$ is still divisible by $p^m$. This is the same as saying that $|f(K)|$ is a power of $p$ and $[H:f(K)]=|H|/|f(K)|$ is not divisible by $p$, right?

OK, I'm fine with the fact that $|f(K)|$ is a power of $p$.

Now for the other part: write $N=\ker f$.

Then we have $$[H:f(K)]=[G/N:KN/N]=[G:KN]$$
using the isomorphism theorems. So since $[G:KN]$ is not divisible by $p$ and $[G:KN]\leq [G:K]$, we get the claim that $[H:f(K)]$ is also not divisible by $p$.

I am unsure about this solution, is it correct?

**I realise this question has been asked twice before but I couldn't fully make sense of the answers and would like feedback to my solution to find flaws in my thinking.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For last few statements (before bold-faced sentence), instead of inequality, you have to notice the following: since $K\subseteq KN \subseteq G$ and since the index of $K$ in $G$ is not divisible by $p$, hence index of $KN$ in $G$ is also not divisible by $p$.

Do you know the relations between indices $[G:K]$, $[G:KN]$ and $[KN:K]$? A relation is in terms of *equality*, not an inequality.

Comment: Thank you. No, I don't know the relation between those indices, could you tell me? One guess is $[G:K]=[G:KN]\cdot|N|$

Comment: Draw a diagram: below, the subgroup $K$, above it the subgroup $KN$ and above it the group $G$; put line between two subgroups. Then from diagram, you should say *Index of $K$ in $G$ is product of index of $K$ in $KN$ and index of $KN$ in $G$*; can you see this in diagram?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if I see it. What exactly am I supposed to see? I drew the diagram and I guess it makes sense what you say.

Comment: See page 298 on this link https://books.google.co.in/books?id=gGJ2c6db8tYC&pg=PA287&dq=degree+of+extensions+fraleigh&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig0NDIwZXNAhUKRY8KHeBfBNkQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=degree%20of%20extensions%20fraleigh&f=false. Similar kind of picture for three groups above and similar relation for indices holds here. From diagram, simply say *biggest index is product of two middle indices; since biggest index is not divisible by $p$ hence smaller middle indices are not divisible by $p$*.